# A curious corollary: there always exists some $c$ such that $2g'(c)h'(c)+g(c)h''(c)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

In a recent [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3898496), it was proved that if $f,g:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ are two twice differentiable functions such that $f(a)=f(b)=g(a)=g(b)=0$ and both $g$ and $g''$ are non-vanishing on $(a,b)$, then $\frac{f(c)}{g(c)}=\frac{f''(c)}{g''(c)}$ for some $c\in(a,b)$.

Now, given any $g$ that satisfies the above premises, if we take $f=gh$, where $h$ is some twice differentiable function, then $f$ is also twice differentiable and the condition that $f(a)=f(b)=0$ is automatically satisfied. Therefore, by the above result,
\begin{aligned}
\frac{f(c)}{g(c)}=\frac{f''(c)}{g''(c)}
&\ \Rightarrow\ h(c)=\frac{g''(c)h(c)+2g'(c)h'(c)+g(c)h''(c)}{g''(c)}\\
&\ \Rightarrow\ g''(c)h(c)=g''(c)h(c)+2g'(c)h'(c)+g(c)h''(c)\\
&\ \Rightarrow\ 2g'(c)h'(c)+g(c)h''(c)=0.\\
\end{aligned}
Hence we obtain the following corollary:

> Let $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be a twice differentiable function such that $g(a)=g(b)=0$ and both $g$ and $g''$ are non-vanishing on $(a,b)$. For every twice differentiable function $h:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$, there exists a point $c\in(a,b)$ such that
> $$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]
> {
> 2g'(c)h'(c)+g(c)h''(c)=0.
> }
> $$

I find this corollary more intriguing than the original problem, because $h$ is basically unrelated to $g$. Are there any direct or intuitive proofs that do not refer to the original problem? Can the assumptions that $g$ and $g''$ are non-vanishing be weakened or even removed from the corollary? (In particular, since the boxed statement does not involve $g''$, I wonder if the corollary is still true when $g$ is only differentiable or $C^1$.)

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I don't understand your point. I am not extracting $h$ from $f$ and $g$. I am picking an $f$ of the form $gh$.

Comment: But your corollary is proved using the conditions $f(a)=f(b)=g(a)=g(b)=0$ so you have to be careful

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Why? If we take $f=gh$ and $g(a)=g(b)=0$, then $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are automatically zero.

Comment: Your corollary can be proved directly by applying Rolle's theorem to $g^2h'$. You only need that $g$ is non-zero.

Comment: @MartinR Great observation! I was thinking about something like an integrating factor, but couldn't come up with this additional $g$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That corollary can be proved directly by applying Rolle's theorem to $g^2h'$. That is not surprising because the statement about $\frac{f(c)}{g(c)}=\frac{f''(c)}{g''(c)}$ is proved by applying Rolle's theorem to $\phi = f'g - fg'$. Substituting  $f=gh$ gives $\phi =g^2h'$.

The non-vanishing of $g''$  on $(a, b)$ in the other question guarantees that one can divide by $g''(c)$, so that condition is not needed here.

Since the corollary only involves $h'$ and the second derivative of $g$ is not needed, it would be more naturally stated as

> Let $g, h:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be differentiable functions such that $g(a)=g(b)=0$ and $g$ is non-vanishing on $(a,b)$. Then there exists a point $c\in(a,b)$ such that
> $$ 
> 2g'(c)h(c)+g(c)h'(c)=0.
> $$

By applying Rolle's theorem to $g^\alpha h$ with $\alpha > 0$ it can be generalized as follows:

> Let $g, h:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be differentiable functions such that $g(a)=g(b)=0$ and $g$ is non-vanishing on $(a,b)$. For every $\alpha > 0$ there exists a point $c\in(a,b)$ such that
> $$ 
> \alpha g'(c)h(c)+g(c)h'(c)=0.
> $$